# How do I get a certain response from a certain input

Tags: python, input, output

Example = If the person types in 20, say that 20 was NOT the correct answer
My current code that I'm trying to work with is:

```
response = (input ('Type a number'))
if response == '5':
print('5 was the correct answer')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `else` and use f-strings to insert the user's input into your response:

```
answer = input('Type a number')
if answer == '5':
    print(f'{answer} was the correct answer')
else:
    print(f'{answer} was NOT the correct answer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an "if" condition for your correct answer, and an else for incorrect ones, while also using proper indents:

```
correct = 5
response = input('Type a number: ')
if response == correct:
    print('5 was the correct answer')
else:
    print(response, "was NOT the correct answer")
```